# Best way to instrument Spring Boot/Java Config Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-java-config

I'd like to keep track of certain things in a Spring Boot/OAuth2/Java Config setting and report those somewhere (think AWS CloudWatch, or Google Analytics, or any other similar services).
To be more precise, I have an Authorization+Resource Server with Spring OAuth2.

Those things I'd like to track would be (though not limited to):

- Login failed attempts (for clients and users)
- Login successful attempts (for clients and users)
- Usage of REST controllers (like "/say_hello_world")
- Exceptions (aside from the authentication ones)

I was planning on adding `javax.servlet.Filters`, but then it gets hairy when logging failed attempts with my Authorization Server (using `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and extending `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`). I think I'd need to either resort to using my custom Exception Translator or figure out how to set/wrap the AuthenticationManager in `ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter`.

Is there a better way than wrapping a tons of things to collect the info I mentioned above?

**Update:**

As I mentioned in the comments, I'm not looking for a "log dump". I need to be able to get for example the user id that tried to login but failed, or the invalid access token that was used, etc.

I looked into coding my own `ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent>`, detect `AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent` and the like and go that route.
For example, I can detect a `BadCredentialsException`, but then need to figure out if it's an InvalidTokenException or other (which is in the cause of that `BadCredentialsException`).
Next problem is that I can't extract the access token that was used and failed. Feels awkward and more hacking than it should.

I don't mind going through hoops like those, just wondered if there was a better way.

**Update2:**

There is one thing that helps "listening" to what's going on in a Spring application and it's the `ApplicationListener`.
Any events published can be caught by providing an implementation of that interface.

1. `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` is published when a client successfully authenticates (i.e. clientId exists and secret key is valid)
2. `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` is published when a user successfully authenticates (i.e. username exists and password matches)
3. `AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent` is published when a user failed authenticating.

There was a problem with #2 and #3 in that in a ProviderManager a NullEventPublisher is setup by default so I had to change my (Java) config like so to get those authentication events:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ... 
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationEventPublisher;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
          .authenticationEventPublisher(authenticationEventPublisher)
          ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now there remains the problem of receiving the event when the client failed authentication.

The `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` is triggered by `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` (which `ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` extends) upon successful authentication. But when authentication fails, it does not publish any event (since at least version [3.0.0](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.unsuccessfulAuthentication%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%2Corg.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException%29) to [4.0.1](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/4.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.unsuccessfulAuthentication%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%2Corg.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException%29)).

Another way would be to configure the `AuthenticationManager` the same way I did above by setting up a non-`NullEventPublisher` but as far as I can tell there's no way to setup `ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` in Spring Boot without manually setting up the universe???

Comment: Use loggers like log4j or slf4j (my prefered)

Comment: I had in mind something more granular and structured. Like getting the username used to login, the HTTP Method used for a request, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AOP in spring. Create advice `@Before`, `@After`, `@Arround` execution of method, or even `AfterThrowing` to detect any exception occured.
Using this approach, you can separate your auditing process from your business logic.

Comment: It is indeed a good way to separate that logic from the rest. I had problems in the past with Spring blowing up because of proxies being proxied by other proxies, etc. I guess I was hoping `ApplicationListener` was used consistently throughout Spring projects (especially Spring Security).